# How to hide scrollbar on overflow: scroll

Tags: css

I'm using

```
overflow: scroll
```

on a menu

how do I hide the scrollbar and still be able to scroll?

Comment: You should make at least ***minimal*** efforts to google.

Answer (score -2):

You cant,thats the whole point of the overflow:scroll; There are ways of styling it but never heard of removing it.

Comment: You can. That's wrong. Since when the scrollbar is the point of `overflow:scroll;`? The point is, obviously, to make the content scrollable.

Comment: would you be so kind to share?

Comment: Google + comments under this question.

Comment: When you make a "you can" statement please prove this... there may be "hacks" such as "http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kurlak/archive/2013/11/03/hiding-vertical-scrollbars-with-pure-css-in-chrome-ie-6-firefox-opera-and-safari.aspx" but this is not a solution...

Comment: If you can't google (sorry, the results coming are pretty straight), then at least **look at the comments under this question.**